# Trouble iterating in python

Tags: python, floating-point, iteration

Working in Python 2.7.

I would like to be able to input a number, and return all the sets of values for x and y that complete the equation win_percentage = observed.

```
def Rlog5(observed):
    z = float(observed)/1000
    for x in range(350, 650, 1):
        y = 1000 - x
        win_percentage = (float(x)-(float(x)*float(y)))/(float(x)+float(y)-(2*(float(x)*float(y))))
        if win_percentage = observed:
           print (z, float(x), float(y))
```

When I run the function, I get nothing. No errors, but no values either (I've tried with and without the floats for x, but I think it needs them because win_percentage should be a float). The most frustrating part is that I have this code which does basically the same thing, and it works fine:

```
def solve(numNuggets):
    for numTwenties in range(0, numNuggets/20 + 1):
            for numNines in range(0, (numNuggets - numTwenties*20)/9 + 1):
                numSixes = (numNuggets - numTwenties*20 - numNines*9)/6
                totNuggets = 20*numTwenties + 9*numNines + 6*numSixes
                if totNuggets == numNuggets:
                    print (numSixes, numNines, numTwenties)
```

I know this kind of a newbie question, but I'm at my wits end...

Comment: You can't possibly have `if win_percentage = observed:` because that's a `SyntaxError`, you need `==` not `=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have noted, you have `=` where you should have `==`, but I assume that's a typo here, since you would get a syntax error.  But you are testing floats for equality, and floats are almost never equal because of their imprecision.  Generally, you test to see if two floats are within a small difference of each other, traditionally called `epsilon`.

Try this:

```
if abs(win_percentage - observed) < 0.000001:
    print etc
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used for assignment, `==` is used for comparison.

Change `if win_percentage = observed:` to `if win_percentage == observed:`.

Comment: If he gets no errors, this can't be the problem. That's why I posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
if win_percentage == observed:
```

Comment: If he gets no errors, this can't be the problem. That's why I posted it as a comment.